# Smoke+fire new showing in viewport not render at all

Tags: smoke-simulation

I have an issue here, i was working on an asteriod project when i realized i cant view my smoke+fire whether in 3D viewport or render, what actually happens is that when i use quick smoke without editing it at first i can see my smoke in 3d view port, but when i try to switch the flow setting from "smoke"to "fire+smoke" then i can't, view anything, not in 3d view or render view at all. i am using blender 2.78

Answer (score 1):

Try to save your blend file and then make a bake of your animation. Your computer can't probably calculate the simulation in time.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Domain

In the Node editor

Before the material are

[image]

We need to add some color to flame (fire)

1. Duplicate the Attribute and change the name from density to flame
2. Add-> convert-color ramp
   (Add the color as shown) You can tweak the color fire has Black at the corner then brown, orange, pale yellow and white (not to be perfect) adjust it.
3. Add a emission with 7.6 emission

Connect the nodes as show below.

[image]

And render hope you get a fire render